# Multiple Request Examples in Swagger 2.0 Yaml

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0

I have an API which has some mutually exclusive arguments for json payloads. I would like to display this in multiple examples but the `schema` in the yaml file seems to only be able to generate one example.

If my inputs could be:

```json
{
  "text": "some text"
}
```

OR

```json
{
  "list": ["some text", "some more"]
}
```

BUT NOT

```json
{
  "text": "some text",
  "list": ["some text", "some more"]
}
```

how can this be done in swagger 2.0?

A schema definition like the following is misleading

```yaml
definitions:
  MutexSchema:
    type: object
    properties:
      list:
        type: array
        items:
          type: string
        example: ["some text", "some more"]
      text:
        type: string
        example: "Some text"
```

And it seems you cannot specify multiple `body` options. What would be a good way to show the mutually exclusive payloads with their corresponding responses?

Answer (score 3):

**OpenAPI 2.0** does not support mutually exclusive properties, but you can emulate this by adding `minProperties: 1` and `maxProperties: 1` to your schema. This essentially means that only `text` or only `list` can be passed, but not both.

```yaml
definitions:
  MutexSchema:
    type: object
    properties:
      list:
        type: array
        items:
          type: string
        example: ["some text", "some more"]
      text:
        type: string
        example: "Some text"
    minProperties: 1   # <--------
    maxProperties: 1
```

> What would be a good way to show the mutually exclusive payloads with their corresponding responses?

Migrate to **OpenAPI 3** which supports [`oneOf`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/oneof-anyof-allof-not/) and [multiple `examples`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples/) for requests and responses. Note that there's no way to *correlate* request and response examples, but you can provide additional information in the `description` fields.

```yaml
paths:
  /something:
    post:
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/MutexSchema'

            # Request body examples
            examples:
              text example:
                summary: Example with text
                value:
                  text: Some text
              list example:
                summary: Example with list
                value:
                  list: [some text, some more]
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                ...

              # Response examples
              examples:
                ex1:
                  summary: ...
                  value:
                    ...
                ex2:
                  summary: ...
                  value:
                    ...

components:
  schemas:
    MutexSchema:
      oneOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Text'
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/List'

    Text:
      type: object
      required:
        - text     # <--- Property must be marked as required for oneOf to work
      properties:
        text:
          type: string
          example: Some text
      additionalProperties: false

    List:
      type: object
      required:
        - list     # <--- Property must be marked as required for oneOf to work
      properties:
        list:
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
          example: [some text, some more]
      additionalProperties: false
```